# Android Profiler: How do I find the leak in my Graphics Memory?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks

My App is very image-heavy and tends to crash when I restart the image heavy part of the app too many times.

Running Android Profiler, it shows me that the Graphics Memory increases by 30 MB everytime, indicating a leak somewhere.

I googled and couldn't find anything about graphics memory leaks. Would appreciate some help!